# Excel Vlookup producing #N/A error when column doesn't match, index instead?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two sheets in a workbook with data pulls from different days to add a new column to the data needed. However, I need to work only with the original data pull (as new items have been added since original pull and those can be ignored). So sheet 1 has 53,875 line items and sheet 2 has 54134 items.

The first column is a user ID, so I have sorted both sheets on that column.

What I would like to do, is take the data from column L on sheet 2, and insert it into a blank column on sheet 1 for `Sheet1!Ax = Sheet2!Ax`. The formula that I came up with is:

`=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1:L1,12,0)`

I then filled it in for the rest of the blank cells in the first sheet. It worked fine, until the first new data item in Sheet 2 failed to match Sheet 1. After that, every cell has the #N/A error.

Is `Vlookup` the correct tool to use for this task, or would it be something else?

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Got a screenshot of the data?

Comment: `Sheet2!A1:L1` doesn't look right. Sure you didn't mean that to be e.g. `Sheet2!$A$1:$L$54134`? The lookup array/range needs to contain all possible values; right now you're only looking at row 1.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - This works: =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A$36,Sheet2!A$1:L$54134,12,0)

Comment: You'll want `$A36`, so that when you copy the formula to rows other than 36, it refers to the correct row :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use :

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!L$1:L$54134,MATCH(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet2!A$1:A$54134,0))
```

Not tested but should work and I tend to find is more stable and possibly quicker than vlookup.

Comment: Agreed. Index+Match is awesome, and in a table you don't need to worry about columns moving. That said, I believe a VLOOKUP wth an approximate match (last parameter set to `True`) over sorted data might beat it, performance-wise. Worth benchmarking :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use tables instead of ranges - a table will automatically expand with new data, an absolute range won't.

Click anywhere in your "source" range, select "Format as Table" from the Home Ribbon (under the "Styles" group). Then do the same for your "target" range.

Now that you have two tables, you can use table formulas and never need to worry about "dragging formulas down" ever again, because the formula is automatically applied to the entire column!

Say you have a `Key` column in `Table1` and `Table2`, and you're looking for the corresponding `Column1` value in `Table2` for each `Key` in `Table1`; the formula could look like this:

```
=VLOOKUP([@Key],Table2[[#All],[Key]:[Column1]],2,FALSE)
```

[image: =VLOOKUP([@Key],Table2[[#All],[Key]:[Column1]],2,FALSE)]

If headings change, the formula updates automatically. If data is added in `Table1`, the lookup formula is automatically added to the new rows. If data is added in `Table2`, the formula doesn't need to be adjusted!

Love tables, they'll love you back!

Comment: Have to have a go with this, looks very handy - nicely explained as well.