# Excel using VLOOKUP as Lookup Value in a VLOOKUP results in value error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016, vba

I have the following excel formula:

```
=IF([@Article]="";"";IF(VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];9;FALSE)="";"";VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];9;FALSE)*wGetConversionRate(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];10;FALSE);Countries[#All];4;FALSE))))
```

Now, it's quite a mouthful, but there's some logic in it. The first two IF's just check if the cells have been filled in.

---

The output of this formula would be an article's cost, converted from its local currency to Euros. The function `wGetConversionRate` is a UDF to get the latest conversion rate from a website (AlphaVantage). The problem is that the local currency in the `Articles` table is not in the international codes, which means I have to use a VLOOKUP as the Lookup Value in another VLOOKUP. The 'nested' VLOOKUP `VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];10;FALSE)` gets the local currency, for example 'Indian Rupee'. Then, the above VLOOKUP `VLOOKUP(*nested VLOOKUP*;Countries[#All];4;FALSE` should return the correct international code for the given currency, for example, 'INR' for 'Indian Rupee'. Instead, it returns a `#VALUE!`, so my guess is that the nested `VLOOKUP`, which returns a string, cannot be used as the lookup value. Is there maybe something I did wrong, or another way around this issue?

The UDF has the following code:

```
Function wGetConversionRate(currencyFrom As String) As Double
' Variables
Dim currencyTo As String
currencyTo = "EUR"
Dim functionAPI As String
Dim from_currencyAPI As String
Dim to_currencyAPI As String
Dim keyAPI As String
Dim stringAPI As String
Dim httpREQ As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim jsonString As String
Dim splitJSONString() As String
Dim exchangeRateString As String
Dim splitExchangeRateString() As String
Dim exchangeRate As Variant

' API String
functionAPI = "CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE"
from_currencyAPI = currencyFrom
to_currencyAPI = currencyTo
keyAPI = "33VEUWOLZGXE1HA9"
stringAPI = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=" + functionAPI + "&from_currency=" + from_currencyAPI + "&to_currency=" + to_currencyAPI + "&apikey=" + keyAPI

' Get JSON string
httpREQ.Open "GET", stringAPI
httpREQ.Send
jsonString = httpREQ.ResponseText

' Split JSON string into usable parts (put into array)
splitJSONString = Split(jsonString, ",")

' Get Exchange Rate item from splitJSONString
exchangeRateString = splitJSONString(4)

' Split exchangeRateString into usable strings (into array)
splitExchangeRateString = Split(exchangeRateString, ":")

' Get exchange rate from splitExchangeRateString
exchangeRateString = Replace(splitExchangeRateString(1), """", "")
exchangeRateString = Replace(exchangeRateString, ".", ",")
exchangeRate = CDec(exchangeRateString)

' Output the exchange rate
wGetConversionRate = exchangeRate
End Function
```

Then the information from the formula evaluation gave me was that when the nested VLOOKUP is calculated it returns a string, and this seems to give an issue in the above VLOOKUP, because it's when it tries to look up the currency using the string as the lookup value, that it returns a `#VALUE!`

Comment: You need to use comas, not **;**

Comment: @urdearboy that's a regional setting, some countries use `;`

Comment: You can analyze your formula with the `Evaluate Formula` tool in Excel. [Evaluate a nested formula one step at a time](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to find at which point your formula gets wrong.

Comment: Use the formula evaluation tool to see where the #VALUE error occurs. My guess would be it's in your UDF, which you haven't posted.

Comment: ① What is the result of `=VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];10;FALSE)`? ② And what is the result of `=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];10;FALSE);Countries[#All];4;FALSE)`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ in the test I'm using, the result of `=VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];10;FALSE)` is 'Euro', which is just the currency it has to get. The result of `=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP([@Article];Articles[#All];10;FALSE);Countries[#All];4;FALSE)` is '#VALUE!', which leads me to believe the issue is in the nested VLOOKUP.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor You're right, the API doesn't accept 'Euro', only international codes like 'EUR', but that's why I'm using the nested VLOOKUP to get the international code for the currency, so for example, that it outputs 'EUR' instead of 'Euro'.

Comment: So the first column of `Countries[#All]` has "Euro" in it?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Well, the third column has "Euro" in it, do you think VLOOKUP only searches on the first column?

Comment: Vlookup indexes on the leftmost column and then moves right according to the number you specify. If you want to index the 11th column and return from the 7th column you need index() with match().

Comment: @S.Weckx That's correct, if you just run VLOOKUP on the 2 columns in question and return the second column that will work, or get used to `INDEX(MATCH())` as stated by Mike (it is a much better formula for many reasons)

Comment: I gave an answer showing a use of index match here if it helps as an example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306029/4961700

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor I think you may be right, thanks a lot man.